# How to specify the order of an axis values in echarts4r

Tags: r, echarts

I'm trying to produce a bar graph with echarts4r but I'm having trouble to specify the order of the values in the axis.

I would like to sort the names ("Estado" variable) according to numerical variable "Casos" (this in decreasing order). I've tried ordered factors without success.

I was able to produce correct output using `ggplot` + `plotly` and also with `highcharter`.

Any help with this?

TIA

Below is my MRE.

```
library(echarts4r)
library(magrittr)

my.df3 <- structure(list(Estado = c("São Paulo", "Rio de Janeiro", "Ceará",  "Pernambuco", "Amazonas", "Maranhão", "Pará", "Bahia", "Espírito Santo",  "Santa Catarina", "Minas Gerais", "Distrito Federal", "Rio Grande do Sul",  "Amapá", "Paraíba", "Alagoas", "Sergipe", "Rio Grande do Norte",  "Paraná", "Acre", "Piauí", "Rondônia", "Roraima", "Goiás",  "Tocantins", "Mato Grosso", "Mato Grosso do Sul"), Casos = c(51097, 18486, 18412, 14309, 14168, 9112, 9059, 6204, 5087, 3733, 3435, 2979, 2917, 2910, 2777, 2580, 2032, 1989, 1930, 1694, 1612, 1460, 1295, 1225, 828, 604, 405), Mortes = c(4118, 1928, 1280, 1157, 1098, 444, 914, 225, 212, 73, 127, 46, 111, 86, 154, 150, 37, 92, 116, 52, 57, 50, 24, 61, 14, 20, 12)), row.names = c(NA, -27L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

my.df3 %>%
  e_charts(x = Estado, elementId = "casos") %>%
  e_bar(Casos, legend = FALSE, name = "Casos") %>% 
  e_labels(position = "right") %>% 
  e_tooltip(
    trigger = "item",
    axisPointer = list(
      type = "line"
    )
  )  %>% 
  e_title("Casos Confirmados") %>% 
  e_flip_coords() %>% 
  e_y_axis(splitLine = list(show = FALSE), axisLabel = list(
    interval = 0L
  )) %>% 
  e_x_axis(show = FALSE) %>% 
  e_toolbox_feature(
    feature = "saveAsImage",
    title = "Save as image"
  ) -> echrtCasos


my.df3 %>%
  e_charts(x = Estado) %>%
  e_bar(Mortes, legend = FALSE, name = "Mortes") %>% 
  e_labels(position = "right") %>% 
  e_tooltip(
    trigger = "item",
    axisPointer = list(
      type = "line"
    )
  ) %>% 
  e_title("Mortes") %>% 
  e_flip_coords() %>% 
  e_y_axis(splitLine = list(show = FALSE), axisLabel = list(
    interval = 0L
  )) %>% 
  e_x_axis(show = FALSE) %>% 
  e_connect("casos") %>%
  e_toolbox_feature(
    feature = "saveAsImage",
    title = "Save as image"
  ) -> echrtMortes

e_arrange(echrtCasos, echrtMortes, rows = 1, cols = 2)
```

[image: graph produced with above code]

The output of sessionInfo() is:

```
R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas/libblas.so.3
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopenblasp-r0.2.20.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=pt_BR.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=pt_BR.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=pt_BR.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=pt_BR.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=pt_BR.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=pt_BR.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=pt_BR.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] echarts4r_0.2.3 magrittr_1.5   

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.4.6         rstudioapi_0.11      tidyselect_1.0.0     xtable_1.8-4         R6_2.4.1            
 [6] rlang_0.4.6          fastmap_1.0.1        dplyr_0.8.5          tools_3.6.3          clipr_0.7.0         
[11] htmltools_0.4.0.9000 ellipsis_0.3.0       yaml_2.2.1           assertthat_0.2.1     digest_0.6.25       
[16] tibble_3.0.1         lifecycle_0.2.0      crayon_1.3.4         shiny_1.4.0.2        purrr_0.3.4         
[21] later_1.0.0          htmlwidgets_1.5.1    vctrs_0.2.4          promises_1.1.0       glue_1.4.0          
[26] mime_0.9             compiler_3.6.3       pillar_1.4.4         jsonlite_1.6.1       httpuv_1.5.2        
[31] pkgconfig_2.0.3
```

Answer (score 1):

It has been a while but I am answering it for the record. You can use reorder parameter (e.g. `e_chart(x,reorder=FALSE)`).

In OP's defense, John Coene (owner of echarts4r package) added this feature after this question was asked:)

Source: https://github.com/JohnCoene/echarts4r/issues/126#issuecomment-585207460

Answer (score 0):

Did you try ggplot:

```
  my.df3 %>% 
      mutate(Estado = reorder(Estado, -Casos)) %>% 
      ggplot(aes(x=Estado, y=Casos))+
      geom_col()+
      coord_flip()

    my.df3 %>% 
      mutate(Estado = reorder(Estado, -Mortes)) %>% 
      ggplot(aes(x=Estado, y=Mortes))+
      geom_col()+
      coord_flip()
```

[image]

Comment: Just realised you tried ggplot. By curiosity, why do you need echarts4R instead of ggplot?

Comment: echarts4r was the only library that allowed me to sync tooltips. Take a look here:
https://momenezes.github.io/covid19/flexboletim_exp.html

Comment: After a while, I found a solution to this problem: adding the `inverse` options to y axis:
`
e_y_axis(splitLine = list(show = FALSE), axisLabel = list(
      interval = 0L
    ), inverse = TRUE)
`